# Cloning the last few posts & comments only

Tags: clone-site

I cloned an entire WP site to a different location a few weeks ago. The new site is being redesigned (but keeping the same content). In the meantime my client posted new posts with comments from her readers.

What's the easiest way to clone those last few posts and comments? If the solution involves PhpMyAdmin, which tables will I be working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use the WordPress export tool. Here you can chose a category and date range so you only export the latest ones. Posts should export with their comments too. Here is a link to the WordPress codex.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen

Comment: I've never had chance with the WP export tool: it NEVER ends (the script nevers stop by himself), plus images often don't work. Also, if I import the website content again there will be duplicates everywhere (posts, categories, etc)

Comment: Please note that although the export tool does not allow an extremely precise specification of the date-range (to the level of timestamp or even date), it DOES [ignore/filter-out duplicates](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/does-the-import-option-in-dashboard-ignore-duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to copy the data of posts and menus just try to use import and export from the tools menu  .
wp-admin/tools.php

or install any backup plugin to help you get all images.